# C++ Construct a class by string

Tags: c++, class, abstract, radix, derived

Let's say I have two classes derived from the same base class. I want to instantiate a new class object depending on the command line input. I could do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DerivedClass1.h"
#include "DerivedClass2.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argv[1] == "DERIVED CLASS 1") {
        DerivedClass1 *myClass = new DerivedClass1(argv[2]);
        myClass->doSomething();
    } else if (argv[1] == "DERIVED CLASS 2") {
        DerivedClass2 *myClass = new DerivedClass2(argv[2]);
        myClass->doSomething();
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this. I'm thinking of creating an abstract class factory, or hard-code map the string names to class instances. 
Couple of restrictions

1) My base class is abstract - it contains purely virtual functions

2) I can only call parameterized constructors

Comment: `argv[1] == "DERIVED CLASS 1"` is a mistake

Comment: You will have to create a factory design pattern. This link might be helpfull https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1

Comment: @M.M whats wrong with that?

Comment: It compares whether `argv[1]` points to the memory location where `"DERIVED CLASS 1"` is stored  (which it never will)

Answer (score 8):

A factory function should work fine:

```
BaseClass* create(std::string const& type, std::string const& arg)
{
    // Could use a map or something instead if there are many alternatives
    if (type == "DERIVED CLASS 1")
        return new DerivedClass1(arg);
    else if (type == "DERIVED CLASS 2")
        return new DerivedClass2(arg);
    else
        return nullptr;  // Or throw an exception or something else
}
```

Use as

```
BaseClass* ptr = create(argv[1], argv[2]);
```

Comment: Why does the type have to be a string const &?

Comment: @ahhhhhjulie You don't have to make it a reference to a constant string object, just plain `std::string` should work in your situation. However, if you want to call it with other strings, passing a reference means less copying. Passing a reference to a constant means you can pass a string literal or temporary object, and also tells the compiler that the function will not modify the function which might enable some optimizations (not likely in this case though) and simplify its semantic checking.